# Regex Replace quotes with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am editing some web log files and I want to remove the double quotes from some feilds, but not all.

For example, in the following line, I want to remove the double quotes from the IP address and server.domain.com, but leave the rest.

```
2013-02-18 21:47:46.636 POST /Path/page.html - - "173.194.79.106" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.296)" - "server.domain.com" 200 1079 15
```

I am looping through the file loading each line with `Foreach-Object`

I can get the line without quotes around the IP address with this:

```
[regex]::replace($_,"`"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`"", '$1')
```

So I attempted to use the below to do the same to the server.domain.com item with this:

```
[regex]::replace($_,"`"[a-zA-Z]*\.[dD][oO][mM][aA][iI][nN]\.[cC][oO][mM]`"",'$1')
```

and my result is this:

```
2013-02-18 21:47:46.636 POST /Path/page.html - - "173.194.79.106" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.296)" - $1 200 1079 15
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you forgot the brackets () in second regex I think

Comment: Thats it!  right in front of my eyes and I missed it!  thanks for being the sounding board!  It should have been: "[regex]::replace($_,"`"([a-zA-Z]*\.[dD][oO][mM][aA][iI][nN]\.[cC][oO][mM])`"",'$1')"

Comment: If you solved the problem, and can you add it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding brackets and using `(?i)` for case-insensitivity:

```
[regex]::replace( $_, "(?i)`"([a-z]*\.domain\.com)`"", '‌​$1' )
```

Alternatively, you could use `-replace` as that is by default case-insensitive

```
$_ -replace "`"([a-z]*\.domain\.com)`"", '$1'
```